# Giving delay in animate.css plugin

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, delay

Hi i am using this plugin called animate.css.

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

I have successfully implemented the animation.. I have 6 icons. I want them to animate one by one in a sequence with a delay of 1 second.. I am not able to achieve the delay in animation. It is all animating at once. Kindly help.

Heres the Html code.

```
<ul class="top_feat">
<li><img src="images/cc.png" class="revealOnScroll "  data-animation="zoomIn"   ></li>
<li>Covered Car Park</li>
</ul>
<ul class="top_feat">
<li><img src="images/club_house.png" class="revealOnScroll"  data-animation="zoomIn" ></li>
<li>Club House</li>
</ul>
<ul class="top_feat">
<li><img src="images/gym.png"  class="revealOnScroll "  data-animation="zoomIn" ></li>
<li>Gymnasium</li>
</ul>
<ul class="top_feat">
<li><img src="images/rec_hall.png"  class="revealOnScroll "  data-animation="zoomIn" ></li>
<li>Recreation Hall</li>
</ul>
```

and heres the jquery for it.

```
<script>
$(function() {

  var $window           = $(window),
      win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1,
      isTouch           = Modernizr.touch;

  if (isTouch) { $('.revealOnScroll').addClass('animated'); }

  $window.on('scroll', revealOnScroll);

  function revealOnScroll() {
    var scrolled = $window.scrollTop(),
        win_height_padded = $window.height() * 1.1;

    // Showed...
    $(".revealOnScroll:not(.animated)").each(function () {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;

      if (scrolled + win_height_padded > offsetTop) {
        if ($this.data('timeout')) {
          window.setTimeout(function(){
            $this.addClass('timeout');
          }, parseInt($this.data('timeout'),10));
        } else {
          $this.addClass('animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
        }
      }
    });
    // Hidden...
   $(".revealOnScroll.animated").each(function (index) {
      var $this     = $(this),
          offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
      if (scrolled + win_height_padded < offsetTop) {
        $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp flipInX lightSpeedIn')
      }
    });
  }

  revealOnScroll();
});


</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could take a look at delay.css: https://github.com/Simonn-/delay.css

Answer (score 2):

Aside from toggling a class to show the elements, you can do this without any JS at all. Simply set up your CSS animation and apply it to all elements, then set a different `animation-delay` value on each individual icon.

**Here's a CodePen to demonstrate:** http://codepen.io/rupl/pen/fCtbx

- Read about [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) on MDN
- Read about [CSS `animation-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) on MDN

If you want this to happen in response to user interaction, consider using CSS Transitions instead (and its equivalent, `transition-delay`):

- Read about [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) on MDN
- Read about [CSS `transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) on MDN

---

**Edit:** Even though I would change your markup if I were authoring it myself so it uses one `<ul>`, I suppose using your exact example I would apply something like this (you'll need to write this code once for each element):

```
.top_feat:nth-of-type(XXX) {animation-delay: YYYs; }
```

- `XXX` would be 1, 2, 3 etc. 1 being the 1st icon, 2 being the 2nd.
- `YYY` would be the delay in seconds. You can also specify `ms` for milliseconds.

Comment: Chris i am using the jquery to trigger the animation when i scroll down to it. I have used a single class name from the css for all the icons to trigger the animation.

@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  
}


I am quite new to css and jquery. I dont understand how to give delay. Kindly help.

Comment: I have removed my comment and added it to my answer because it contained code examples.